# How to set up a fabric network v2 on 2 machines?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to set up the HLF first network on 2 vms. So, i created 2 yaml files each for every machine.

Machine 1:
- 1 orderer
- 2 peers
- 2 couchdb
- 1 ca

Machine 2:
- 2 peers
- 2 couchdb
- 1 ca

There is no problem to fetch block 0 and i am able to create the channel and finally to install the chaincode. However, when i am trying to to approve a chaincode definition for my orgs, i receive the same error from both machines.

**Error: failed to retrieve broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7050: connect: connection refused"**

P.S. Sorry about the big post i am trying to be specified in case someone can find my faults

i checked my containers:

```
docker logs orderer.example.com
```

Output:

```
2020-06-15 13:33:43.211 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 05a Error reading from 160.40.55.128:41374: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2020-06-15 13:33:43.211 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 05b streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=160.40.55.128:41374 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=25.77361ms
2020-06-15 13:35:06.984 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 05c Error reading from 160.40.55.128:41380: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2020-06-15 13:35:06.984 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 05d streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=160.40.55.128:41380 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=35.920976ms
```

For peer0 machine1

```
docker logs peer0.Org1.example.com
```

Output:

```
020-06-15 14:17:25.473 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 4728 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=<this is ip machine2>:51022
2020-06-15 14:17:25.473 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 4729 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=<this is ip machine2>:40848
```

For peer0 machine2

```
docker logs peer0.Org2.example.com
```

Output:

```
2020-06-15 14:42:42.257 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 19ab [[mychannel] Membership view has changed. peers went offline:  [[peer1.org1.example.com:7051 ]] , current view:  [[peer1.org2.example.com:7051] [peer0.org1.example.com:7051 ]]]
2020-06-15 14:42:42.823 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 19ac Failed obtaining connection for peer1.org1.example.com:7051, PKIid:0a1afd4de6bc1b118a4a3d455045b67979b757e7f1936283ab27d106f0674aa1 reason: context deadline exceeded
```

node1.yaml:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/priv_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/priv_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2:IP_MACHINE2'
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2:IP_MACHINE2'
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_certh
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2:IP_MACHINE2'
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '5984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_certh
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2: IP_MACHINE2'
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '6984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer    
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca1.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'    
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
      - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
      - ./ccp:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/ccp
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

node2.yaml:
    version: '2'

```
volumes:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:
  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/priv_sk
    ports:
      - '7054:7054'
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/priv_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'ca_peerOrg1:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'orderer.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_certh
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb2:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production   
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'ca_peerOrg1:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'orderer.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb2
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb2:
    container_name: couchdb2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '7984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_certh
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb3:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer1.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'ca_peerOrg1:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'orderer.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 10051:7051
      - 10053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb3
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb3:
    container_name: couchdb3
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '8984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer   
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'ca_peerOrg1:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'orderer.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'   
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
      - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
      - ./ccp:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/ccp
    depends_on:
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Configtx.yaml:

---

```
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg

        ID: OrdererMSP

        MSPDir: ../first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.example.com:7050

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2

        Name: Org2MSP

        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: ../first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true     
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt

    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities


Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HectorCode, I made some changes to `node1.yml` file as I'm assuming that u are running both the Org1 peers on same VM hecne you can't use port `7051` for both `peer0` and `peer1`. Similarly make changes to `node2.yml` based on these.

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/priv_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/priv_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2:IP_MACHINE2'
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2:IP_MACHINE2'
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_certh
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:IP_MACHINE1'
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '5984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_certh
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'ca_peerOrg2: IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peero.org1.example.com:INSTANCE_IP1'
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '6984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer    
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer1.org2.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:IP1'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:IP1'
      - 'orderer.example.com:IP1'
      - 'ca1.example.com:IP_MACHINE2'    
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
      - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
      - ./ccp:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/ccp
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your channel configuration file (configtx.yaml). You have defined the same ports for Anchors peers on both Organization.

Org2 (Presently):

```
AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
          Port: 7051
```

(Org2) Change it to :

```
 AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 9051
```

Comment: I assume that  should i change on node2.yaml peer0.org2.example.com & peer1.org2.example.com to port 8051 both of them?

Comment: Not both of them.Every peer would have different port. For Org2, if peer0 is 8051 then peer1 would be 9051. Same goes for Org1 for example if peer0 is at 6051 then peer1 would be at  7051.

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal If the peer's are running on different VM's then it is not mandatory to use different ports for every peer. you can use `7051` for every peer as long as peers are on different machine.

Comment: @alpha As long as the hostname is different you can have same port number.But if you follow the question thoroughly it is mentioned that On Machine 1 we have all peers.That's why anchor peers same port issue is there.And you have mentioned the same thing in your answer.

Comment: @alpha @ShubhamJaiswal thank you for your help i changed AnchorPeers port but still i   am facing issues. I installed chaincode successfully but when i am trying to `peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name mycc --version 1.0 --init-required --package-id $CC_PACKAGE_ID --sequence 1 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem` i receive the same error.

Comment: @alpha @ShubhamJaiswal i am using docker logs to find the error for peers. On the 1st machine the output is `2020-06-18 10:18:24.902 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 055 TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.21.0.1:46206
2020-06-18 10:18:24.908 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 056 TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.21.0.1:46210` but i have not set anywhere IP=172.21.0.1. Do you know what is that IP?

Comment: @alpha @ShubhamJaiswal However, on the second machine i receive the same error but `2020-06-18 10:12:36.514 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 031 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=<IP of the first machine>:33766`. I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the firewall is inactive. I think that is a communication error between peers and orderer but i do not know what is going wrong

Comment: @HectorCode. You have missed the orderer flag(- o) in your command.You have provided the tls cert path though. Here is an example of that command :             `peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg  -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID mychannel --name mycc --version 1.0 --init-required --package-id myccv1:a7ca45a7cc85f1d89c905b775920361ed089a364e12a9b6d55ba75c965ddd6a9 --sequence 1 --signature-policy "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')" `

Comment: @ Shubham Jaiswal i could not imagine this because i am using the commands from [link] (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html).  Based on this i used with success `peer lifecycle chaincode checkcommitreadiness -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --channelID mychannel --name mycc --version 1.0 --init-required --sequence 1 --signature-policy "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"`

Comment: @ Shubham Jaiswal but this one `peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --channelID mychannel --name mycc --version 1.0 --init-required --sequence 1 --signature-policy "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"` fails with the output `Error: transaction invalidated with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE)`. Do you think is it a command issue again? Or policy from configtx.yaml?
`

Comment: Okay that means you are not using any specific endorsement policy in your network.You can remove the signature policy flag in the command and then try again and have you changed the anchor peers port in the configtx.yaml?